# Does it matter what side integration constant is on?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My problem is when solving separable differential equations,  there will be two integrals on either side of the equation (something like $\int(x^2 - x) dx= \int(y^2 +4) dy$), won't the sign of C (constant of integration) change depending on which side you put it on? Does it matter since C is arbitrary?

Comment: A constant is a constant dosent matter where you put it. C can be any number positive or negative

Comment: You get a constant on each side, $C_1, C_2$, then you can simply define $C = C_2 - C_1$.